# Need to understand the usage of under or below

Tags: grammar

Is this correct english " Ram is standing below my building" or "Ram is standing downstairs"

Answer (score 3):

If you say that something is "under the building" or "below the building", that would normally be understood to mean under the ENTIRE building, like something buried beneath the basement, or the ground beneath the building.

If I am on the third floor and Ram is on the second floor, I could not say, "Ram is under the building." No he's not: he's inside the building. I could say, "Ram is on the floor under mine", or "In this building, Ram is below me".

"Downstairs" and "upstairs" are commonly used to describe this kind of physical relationship. "Ram is downstairs": he is on a floor below the floor where I am now. "Ram is upstairs": he is on a floor above the floor where I am now.

"Downstairs" and "upstairs" are also used in an absolute sense to refer to upper and lower parts of a building. "The executive offices are upstairs": they are on an upper floor. I'd be especially likely to use the words this way if I am not presently in the building. This is most commonly used when a building only has two floors, so clearly the first floor is "downstairs" and the second floor is "upstairs". If a building has 50 floors, it would not be at all clear what you mean by "upstairs". The very top floor? The top 25? Etc.